# Nginx on Docker - proxy_pass to Directory gives 404

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm using Nginx on Docker and trying to use proxy_pass to pass a port to a directory. In this case, port 9000 to /data. The root / directory works correctly, but anything that passes to a directory gives a 404 error. What could be wrong here?

See below for details:

to run the container, I run:

```
docker run -v /home/uhc/docker/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/ -e DOMAIN=portal.websitename.org -e EMAIL=data@websitename.edu -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --name nginx --restart=always --net=host -d andreilhicas/nginx-letsencrypt
```

default.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name portal.websitename.org;

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/certbot;
  }
  location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name portal.websitename.org;
    ssl_certificate /usr/share/nginx/certificates/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/share/nginx/certificates/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/ssl-options/options-nginx-ssl.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl-options/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://0.0.0.0:5000;
    }

    location /data/ {
      proxy_pass  http://0.0.0.0:9000;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /data2/ {
      proxy_pass  http://0.0.0.0:8000;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your requirement correctly, but it seems like you are trying to map a port to a directory which is not possible afaik. `proxy_pass` is used to pass traffic from a specific URL to another service (e.g. an application-server) on that specific port. If it is that what you mean, you need to provide more information: What is actually running on port 9000?

Comment: @DavidLosert yep, I have three servers running on three different ports. Port 80: CKAN, Port 8000: WordPress, Port 9000: KeyCloak